# Using Junior Framework with Meteor (Jr not defined)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, meteor

So I'm currently working on my first meteor app which will be a nice mobile app.
Since it will only run on mobile devices I want to use the [Junior Framework](http://justspamjustin.github.io/junior/#home) to achieve the look and feel of a classic app + the slide transitions.

It is based on backbone.js.

So my meteor app also already uses backbone and works just fine. Problem is now that when I include junior into my meteor project the Junior namespace ("Jr") is NOT defined.

I think that this has the following reason:
Meteor always automatically wraps any *.js file from within the project with the following code:

```
(function(){ ... }).call(this);
```

This destroys the class definition of the [junior js class](http://justspamjustin.github.io/junior/src/javascripts/junior.js) which results in "Jr" not defined.

How can I get around this? I really need Junior to use the slide transitions and everything.

Or let's put it another way: Do you know of any way to include slide transitions between pages within a meteor project which is also using backbone.js (at the moment I'm using a standard backbone router + Meteor's Template.templatename.var syntax)?

Thank you in advance,
best regards

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Where are you putting your CSS + JS for Junior?

You should put all this 3rd party stuff in folder "public" (it will be not bundled as meteor js, but as 3rd party js + css. http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

I created quick demo I putt all in there and

## HTML

```html
<head>
    <title>junior</title>
    <script src="lib/javascripts/modernizr.custom.15848.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/javascripts/zepto.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/javascripts/zepto.flickable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/javascripts/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/javascripts/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/javascripts/junior.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/stylesheets/ratchet.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/stylesheets/junior.css"/>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <div id="app-container">
    <div id="app-main">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        {{greeting}}
        <input type="button" value="Click" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

## JavaScript

```js
// then i'm able to get Jr object on client side (anywhere)
console.log(Jr);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer rudovjan! here's my current folder structure: http://i.imgur.com/i7tWJ2e.png
Does it really have to be named "public" so it is not wrapped with this strange "(function(){..."? So what you are doing is basically naming my "client" folder "public" ... right? or do I have to rename my "lib" folder with the "junior" folder in it?
btw: "views" contains all my .html .js files corresponding to the view loaded via backbone.

Comment: Hi Patrick, you should create public folder on same level as client and move there your lib directory. After that you will be able reach your Junior from index.html by using src="lib/javascripts/modernizr.custom.15848.js"

Answer (score 0):

So junior will not do the job!

First and foremost: slide transitions are still very buggy and slow to this date on mobile devices. So only include them if you really need them.
If you then still are looking for a way to have sliding transitions within a meteor project I suggest to have a look at: [Tom C's transitioner](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-transitioner/)

It does not work perfectly but it is by far the best solution out there right now!